# AngularJS: scope change in ngClick gets lost

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-class

I have ngClick and ngClass on an element duplicated by ngRepeat:

```
<li
    ng-class="{'active': $parent.mem.A == $key, 'not-active': $parent.mem.A && $parent.mem.A != $key}"
    ng-repeat="($key, A) in As"
    ng-click="$parent.mem.A = $key">
```

Inside the `li` I have a button that changes the value of `$parent.mem.A` onClick:

```
<button ng-click="$parent.mem.A = $parent.findInHash('prev','A')">Activate previous</button>
```

`findInHash()` returns the expected value, and when I step through angular, the value in $scope.$apply() from ngEventDirective is correct; but somewhere it's getting lost.

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jshado1/8dex3/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your code all ng-click are executed when you click on the button

you just need to stop the event propagation like the following sample

```
$scope.findInHash = function ($event, dir, attr) {
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $event.preventDefault();
    ...


<button ng-click="$parent.mem.A = $parent.findInHash($event,'prev','A')">...
```

Comment: Ugh of course. You're a godsend. Thanks! I was about to loose my mind.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the `button`, the click event is propagated to the `li` element and its `ng-click` is executed as well.

In `ng-click` the `$event` variable is available so you can easily use it to stop event propagation:

```
<button ng-click="$parent.mem.A = $parent.findInHash('prev','A');$event.stopPropagation();">Activate previous</button>
```